# Conflict between ifxetex and ucs under pdflatex/xelatex - why?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, packages, incompatibility

I use TexLive 2012 (on Mac) and the following minimal example does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs} % Need newline here!
\ifxetex
\else
\fi

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The above example does not compile unless I add at least one extra newline after the comment, as you can see in the log at the end. The garbled characters are garbled in the error message.

I have a workaround, and that source isn't even what I need to write (in the end, I shouldn't load `ucs` if I'm using xetex, so its loading should also be conditional), but I still wonder about the best course of action for reporting this.

1. What could cause the error?
2. Could I be running into more silent errors?
3. How can I report this best? Should I bother the `ifxetex` author (it's a very small package) or just the `ucs` one?
4. Is this kind of question itself appropriate?

Here's the error I get. It seems that loading ucs didn't complete.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./bug.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian,
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian,
welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uninames.dat
! Undefined control sequence.
G...tempcnta by1\relax \ifnum \@tempcnta =\uc@got
                                                  \expandafter \uncompress \...
l.241 G
       Ч�ϑ������ĵٵׂԞ��
? X
No pages of output.
Transcript written on bug.log.
```

Here's the result with the extra newline. Most notably, `ucs` loads a *different* file, if I interpret the output correctly.

I can't spot significant differences with XeLaTeX's behavior, in both cases.

```
$ pdflatex bug
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./bug.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian,
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian,
welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def))
(./bug.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
(./bug.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on bug.log.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the way `ucs` emulates LaTeX kernel features. If you read the code, you'll find:

```
\ifx\@ifnextchar\undefined
  \def\@ifnextchar#1#2#3{%
    \let\reserved@d=#1%
    \def\reserved@a{#2}%
    \def\reserved@b{#3}%
    \futurelet\@let@token\@ifnch}\fi
```

which looks safe enough, but fails in the case where the immediately preceding use of `\@let@token` was by `\newif`. That's because it is the `\let` to `\iffalse`, meaning that the conditional is unbalanced and everything 'runs away'. What is needed to to make `\@let@token@` 'safe', for example by inserting

```
\let\@let@token\relax
```

just before this test (or indeed anywhere earlier). As such, the link to `ifxetex` is coincidental, and it's a bug in `ucs`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I managed to apply the change you propose - I'm don't know enough real TeX to fully follow the answer or get the code, but I'll point to your report. I also verified that the latest Texlive 2012 update didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have incorporated the patch suggested by Joseph Wright into the *ucs* package. The updated package should soon appear on CTAN under version number 2.2.